# Selenium - Long running test cases fails when machine goes into sleep mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver

I am running Selenium regression test suite for our website using IE Driver. These test cases takes around 8 hours to complete. I am running these test cases on AWS workspace i.e. on remote machine. However i have made one observation. Whenever my machine goes into Sleep mode, test cases start failing. When these test cases are run normally on machine which doesn't go into sleep mode, they seem to be passing. I just wanted to confirm if this is expected behavior? If this is, what is the solution? I am not sure if this problem is specific to AWS workspace or this is expected behavior for Selenium test cases?

**Update** Test case involves calling an action to hover over a menu and show sub menu. Is there a possibility that this may not run because of above mentioned machine condition?

Comment: Ambiguous question.
A test can be ANYTHING， and you try to assume it is a generic issue. 
A test case that involved remote connection will prone to fail when system goes hibernating. There is not easy solution for such situation.

Comment: I have added few comments...On further analysis it feels like issue comes due to Actions which navigate users to certain page... However i am still not sure on what causes this above mentioned issue

Comment: If you want to confirm your case, just put it inside local VM and run it. During the test, just suspend the session from time to time, and resume them.  Write down each break point success and failure until you encounter the problem. Unless all webpages are host locally inside the same VM, there is no guarantee that resuming a "sleep VM session" will recover the connection, this is nothing to do with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's should be the normal behavior for IEDriver, The solution may be to use headless browser for example selenium PhantomJS.

8 hours its big time for browser testing (for best result i suggest
to separate the test)